# Performance of a view in Oracle very slow

Tags: oracle, performance, sql-view

I have a complex view joining multiple tables. The SQL query returns 22 million records in 50 minutes.

My query is

```
select * from view where last_update_ts is yesterday;
```

This query is run everyday which would only return approximately 3000 records. However, it still performs the join on the multiple tables which is 22 million and then applies filter for `last_update_ts` which takes about 50 minutes everyday.

Is there a way to improve the performance of this view ?
Is there a way where I can first apply the `last_update_ts` and do the join which would only join 3000 records instead of 22 million ?

Comment: Paste the code for the view, and paste the execution plan.

Comment: `where last_update_ts is yesterday` is not valid SQL syntax.